# Search MySQL Database for Bookmarks that are related / contain multiple Tag records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, tags

I want to add the capability to search my Bookmark MySQL records using PHP and be able to combine 2-3 Tags to filter my results to records that contaain all the tags in my search instead of the typical search for all records containing a single tag value.

Pinboard.in a bookmark service allows you to search/filter your bookmarks site-wide and on a specific user account with up to 3 tags filtering the result.

---

Pinboard HowTo Page (https://pinboard.in/howto/#rss) says:

You can filter feeds by up to three tags:

```
http://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/u:username/t:tag1/t:tag2/
http://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/u:username/t:tag1/t:tag2/t:tag3/
http://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/t:tag1/t:tag2/
```

---

I currently have a `Users` DB table, `Tags` DB table, `Bookmark` table, and `tag_to_bookmark` relation table

I can get all Tags related to a BOokmark record with this SQL:

```
SELECT tags.name
  FROM tags
  JOIN bookmark_tag_relationship ON tags.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.tag_id
  JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.bookmark_id
 WHERE bookmarks.id = $bookmarkId
```

---

And get all Bookmarks for a single Tag with this SQL:

```
SELECT bookmarks.name
  FROM bookmarks
  JOIN bookmark_tag_relationship ON bookmarks.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.bookmark_id
  JOIN tags ON tags.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.tag_id
 WHERE tags.id = 1
```

---

**Now how can I make my SQL return Bookmarks that contain 1, 2, or 3 tags?**

---

My DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmark_tag_relationship (
  bookmark_id NUMERIC,
  tag_id TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE bookmarks (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id NUMERIC,
  name TEXT,
  description TEXT,
  url TEXT,
  project_url TEXT,
  github_url TEXT,
  demo_url TEXT,
  local_demo_url TEXT,
  image1 TEXT,
  image2 TEXT,
  image3 TEXT,
  image4 TEXT,
  notes TEXT,
  category TEXT,
  tags TEXT,
  click_count NUMERIC,
  created DATETIME,
  last_viewed DATETIME,
  active NUMERIC
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id NUMERIC,
  name TEXT,
  description TEXT,
  color TEXT,
  bookmark_count NUMERIC,
  active NUMERIC
);

CREATE TABLE users(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   NUMERIC,
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT,
  user_name TEXT,
  email TEXT,
  password TEXT,
  website TEXT,
  photo_url TEXT,
  bookmark_count NUMERIC,
  active NUMERIC
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood properly (you want retrieve all bookmarks having - i.e. - tags.id=1 AND tags.id=2), for me this query works:

```
  SELECT bookmarks.id, bookmarks.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as foundtags
    FROM tags
    JOIN bookmark_tag_relationship ON tags.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.tag_id
    JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.bookmark_id
   WHERE ( tags.id IN (1,2) )
GROUP BY bookmarks.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 2
```

The `SELECT / FROM / JOIN` is the same of your query to get all tags related to a bookmark, the `WHERE` condition matches tags with id in specified values (‘OR’ operator), `GROUP BY` groups results by `bookmarks.id` and - last but essential - `HAVING` filters results with 2 tags (without it the query returns bookmarks having tags.id =1 OR tags.id=2).

With a simple edit, the query can search by tag name instead of tag id:

```
  SELECT bookmarks.id, bookmarks.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as foundtags
    FROM tags
    JOIN bookmark_tag_relationship ON tags.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.tag_id
    JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.bookmark_id
   WHERE ( tags.name IN ('tag1','tag2') )
GROUP BY bookmarks.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 2
```

To simply retrieve bookmarks with 2, 3 or more tags you can use following function, that you can use whether as `queryTag(1)` or as `queryTag(1,2)` or as `queryTag(3,5,6)` etc...:

```
function queryTags()
{
    return "
            SELECT bookmarks.id, bookmarks.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as foundtags
              FROM tags
              JOIN bookmark_tag_relationship ON tags.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.tag_id
              JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.id = bookmark_tag_relationship.bookmark_id
             WHERE ( tags.id IN (".implode(',',func_get_args()).") )
          GROUP BY bookmarks.id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = ".func_num_args()."
    ";
}
```

I would have liked to return ALL tags of each retrieved bookmarks (when the bookmark has more than searched tags)... but I have not been able!